# In App Billing - launchPurchaseFlow invalid parameter

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in-app-billing in my app and followed the google tutorial.
But when i try to pass my sku (Already configured with an id in developer console)  as a string parameter it keep's telling me that it is an invalid symbol.

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, pacote1, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "pct120160503");
```

`Error:(253, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable pacote1`

If i replace pacote 1 whith a variable i keep receiving this error:

Error:(35, 35) error: unreported exception IabAsyncInProgressException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: So `pacote1` is a string varible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call this method with try and catch:

```
try {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, pacote1, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "pct120160503");
}
catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {

}
```